# "Execution was interrupted" when use Date in playground. Can anyone explain this?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

When I use a property with the type Date in playground in XCode-beta 11, I get an error: "Execution was interrupted". (in Xcode 10 everything is fine )

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJJPb.jpg)

Xcode 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v)

```
import Foundation

class Singleton {
  static let shared = Singleton()
  private init() {}

  let date = Date()
}

let singleton = Singleton.shared // Error here (when instance created)
print("DATE:", singleton.date)
```

Comment: Is this a bug report or a question?

Comment: Edit title of question. 
I think, I don' understanding some basics principles. Maybe somebody can explain this situation.